# Install ArgoUML into Eclipse Indigo throw an error

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo, argouml

I was trying install [ArgoUML](http://argoeclipse.tigris.org/documentation/download.html) into Eclipse Indigo, anyhow I hit this error during the installation and proceed, any clue to solve this problem?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.1.20110909-1818 (epp.package.jee 1.4.1.20110909-1818)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.3.2.v201111030500-7b7II1YFSK2WIuPRDEnExPV-RvTn (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group 3.3.2.v201111030500-7b7II1YFSK2WIuPRDEnExPV-RvTn) requires 'org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.core [1.0.301.v201108240656]' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.1.20110909-1818 (epp.package.jee 1.4.1.20110909-1818)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.4.1.20110909-1818]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.4.1.20110909-1818 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.20110909-1818)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
```

Comment: I would like to migrate this question to Superuser.com. Can anyone help?

Comment: Added a vote to close and move to superuser.  But, you can just re-ask this same question on superuser.  I'll take a stab at it below anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you are missing a required update site.  From the error log, `org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.core [1.0.301.v201108240656]` is required, but couldn't be found.  A quick google search shows that this should be part of WTP 3.2.x.  You can find all the update sites for WTP here; http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/  Choose one of the 3.2.x update sites and make sure that you have "Contact all update sites..." checked when you try to install ArgoUML.